# How to use UserForm CheckBox to change Control Content CheckBox in Word Document?

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I created an *UserForm* with a checkbox `'cbxYes'` and a Content Control checkbox `'docCbx'` in the Word document.  I want to be to check off the checkbox `'cbxYes'`  in *UserForm* that then changes the Content Control checkbox in the Word document. 
So the input is from the *UserForm* checkbox and the output is the Content Control checkbox.

I have tried multiple searches on how to do this, but I could not find exactly what I needed. Most of the searches were related to Excel.  And honestly, I don't know what I'm doing.  Please.  The correct help is greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub cbxYes_Click()

Dim oCC As ContentControl

If cbxYes.value = True Then
   cbxYes.value = "True"
   ActiveDocument.docCbx_Yes.value = True
Else
   cbxYes.value = "False"
   ActiveDocument.docCbx_Yes.value = False
End If

End Sub
```

The error I got was:

> run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code shown in the question would be for ActiveX checkboxes, rather than content controls. (Just to make things really complicated, Word also has checkbox *form fields* that need yet another code syntax.)

There's no way to refer directly to a content control name via the `Document` object - it must be done over the `ContentControls` collection. Content controls can be assigned a `Title` and/or a `Tag` in the Properties dialog box.

[image]

More than one content control can have the same name or title, which makes the code a bit complicated. Querying `Document.ContentControls("Title")` returns a collection (all the content controls with that title).

If you know which one, then it's possible to pick it up directly (rather than working through a collection) using the `Item` method, specifying that it's the *n* content control (the index in the order of content controls). This is usually used when one *knows* there's only the one.

Note, please, also, that in order to "check" or "uncheck" a content control checkbox the `Checked` property should be use. So:

```
Private Sub cbxYes_Click()

Dim oCC As ContentControl
Set oCC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("docCbx").Item(1)

If cbxYes.value = True Then
   'cbxYes.value = "True" not needed
   occ.Checked = True
Else
   'cbxYes.value = "False" not needed
   oCC.Checked = False
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "docCbx" is the *title* of the content control you can replace

```
ActiveDocument.docCbx_Yes.value = True
```

by

```
For Each oCC In  ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("docCbx")
  If (oCC.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox) Then 
    oCC.Checked = False
  End If
Next
```

and the equivalent, but using False, for the other branch of your code. The above code will update *all checkbox type* content controls with that name (the names do not have to be unique within a document), except controls that have been marked as "Contents cannot be edited" - they will remain unchanged. It deals with the situation where there aren't any content controls with that name by *doing nothing*.

If "docCbx" is the value of the *Tag*, you would need the following instead:

```
For Each oCC In  ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("docCbx")
  If (oCC.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox) Then 
    oCC.Checked = False
  End If
Next
```

If docCbx is something else, I would suggest that instead you give Titles and/or Tags to your content controls and use the above approach. Otherwise, you should modify your question to state precisely how you are naming the control "docCbx".

You get the error because adding content controls to a document does not create new members of the document object, whereas adding a form control to a user form does create new members of the Form object. (Documents do in fact have a mechanism that works more like the Form object but it has been deprecated for a long time.)

Comment: Thank you, thank you Cindy Meister!  Your code works!  I now see that I needed to create the ContentControl object in VBE and then set that ContentControl object in reference to the active document selected ContentControls by location. I didn't know the code language that refers to the location in the active document.  Thanks again Cindy, you are fabulous!! Thank you for your contribution as well yokki.  I tried your code but it didn't work because I don't think the code associated to the object to the active document object.